# Moving App Folder to other location

Tags: magento-1, security, app

I have already searched on google this question and I already ended up with no success. Ok basically the title of my question says it all.. **Is there any possibility that I can set my app folder in a different location on my server?**

Basically, the reason for me to move the app folder to other location is for security.

Comment: You need to start here: http://alanstorm.com/magento_base_directories